# JSTL cannot receive data from server

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

I am working with SpringMVC3.2 and JSP and I am trying to display user information. But I have problem to display it on JSP page.

Here are my controller and JSP page:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/map")
public class EventDataController {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventDataController.class);

    @Autowired EventDataService eventDataService;
    @Autowired UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index() {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("devicemap");

        UserDetails sessionUser = SecurityUtils.currentUserDetails();
        User user = userService.findUser(sessionUser.getUsername());
        log.info("user==>" + user);
        if (user==null){
            mv.addObject("error", "Cannot find user.");
        } else {
            mv.addObject("user", user);
                }
        return mv;
    }

}

devicemap.JSP

<span class="alert" id="userInfo">
  <c:choose>
     <c:when test="${!empty user}">
        ${user.userId}
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
       User not found
    </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>
</span>


applicationContext.xml

    <!-- ViewResolver for JSP -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

When I check the user object in the controller, it has user data and devicemap.jsp is in WEB-INF/pages.

What have I done wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It worked when I changed the key name in the ModelAndView to any different instead of 'user'. Is 'user' a reserved keyword in JSTL?

Comment: I don't think `user` is a keyword of JSTL. After changing the key name, did you try to change it back to `user` again? If it works and your server is `Tomcat`, i guess the reason is that the `jsp` file was cached in the `work` folder. Could you try and give some feedback?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong the  condition to check the 'user' is not proper.

You should use

```
<c:when test="${not empty user}">
```

or

```
<c:when test="${user ne null}">
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Thanks but user was empty when I used just ${user}.

Answer (score 1):

Well according to me you have make mistake in JSTL syntax so use  for the printing Data or just see follows.

```
<C:if test="${!empty user}">


</c:if>
```

or you can do this things too.

```
 <c:when test="${not empty user}">
    </c:when>
```

or u can do this too.

```
 <c:when test="${!empty user}">
    </c:when>
```

try this and your pron will be short out.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the `JstlView` to your `InternalResourceViewResolver`.

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" 
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This will ensure that the EL expressions in your JSP are correctly evaluated.

Comment: This is done automatically... also JstlView just contains some localization stuff.

Comment: Thanks guys. I agree with @Pavel. I do not have any issue when I use JSTL expression in any page except my question.